Get suffix using NEOS Server in Pyomo
I'm using Pyomo and Neos server as Solver Manager, but I don't know how to get the suffixes or dual variables. I tried coding model.dual = Suffix(direction=Suffix.IMPORT_EXPORT) before solving the model but It doesn't work.
This is the code:
model.dual = Suffix(direction=Suffix.IMPORT_EXPORT)
solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory('neos')
results= solver_manager.solve(model, solver="ipopt")
model.dual.pprint()

But it returns empty.
I would like to obtain the dual variables specifically of a constraint, but I don't get dual variables of nothing.
